# iOS Link to external page

Tags: ios, objective-c, hyperlink, storyboard

Having read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7116393/how-to-create-a-button-that-links-to-safari), I'm trying to insert a link to an external web page calling an action upon `touch inside` on a button (button created in storyboard with xCode 4.6).

This is the action:

```
-(IBAction)outLink:(id)sender {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"https://www.mysite.com/index.php"]];
}
```

and this the header file (`.h`):

```
@interface MenuViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITabBarControllerDelegate>{
    IBOutlet UIButton *linkToSite;
}

-(IBAction)outLink;
```

I have linked the button to the element in the storyboard, and I've linked the action to the `Touch Up Inside` event, but I get this error when I click in the simulator on the button:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MenuViewController outLink]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x717d340'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change method name in .h class and reconnect your outlet for touchupinside event.

```
-(IBAction)outLink:(id)sender;
```

Hope it helps you.